# LibGDX IllegalStateException: frame buffer couldn't be constructed: unsupported combination of formats

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

I wrote application using LibGDX, tested it on several devices. It works, but when I loaded application to Play.google, I received information about bugs and crashes:

**full stack trace:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: frame buffer couldn't be constructed: unsupported combination of formats 
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FrameBuffer.build(FrameBuffer.java:183) 
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FrameBuffer.<init>(FrameBuffer.java:97) 
at com.me.screens.DirectedGame.setScreen(DirectedGame.java:32) 
at com.me.pidgame.MyGdxGame.create(MyGdxGame.java:16) 
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:334) 
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1505) 
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

Why does it appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source: [FrameBuffer](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/FrameBuffer.java#L182).

You will see that that exception is thrown when the result of `gl.glCheckFramebufferStatus` in the OpenGL context returns a `GL20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED`

```
if (result == GL20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED)
    throw new IllegalStateException("frame buffer couldn't be constructed: unsupported combination of formats");
```

This happens when the [Pixmap.Format](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Pixmap.Format.html) used to create the FrameBuffer is not supported in that particular device.